# Error splitting .mov file with ffmpeg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I have used the following ffmpeg command to split the given media file.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:07:00 -acodec copy -vcodec copy test1.mov
```

The video "test.mov" has the following characteristics:

```
Dimensions: 320 * 240
Codecs: MPEG-4 Video, ACC
Duration: 00:45
Audio channels: 2
Total bit rate: 1,292
```

But while splitting it shows the following errors

```
FFmpeg version 0.6, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
built on Apr 29 2011 12:03:13 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
configuration: --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --disable-indev=jack --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
[aac @ 0x10181e200]channel element 1.0 is not allocated
    Last message repeated 215 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x10180b000]max_analyze_duration reached

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/sts-107-/Dev/cloudfactory/tmp/media/test.mov':
  Duration: 00:00:45.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1297 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1195 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, s16, 97 kb/s
File '/Users/sts-107-/Dev/cloudfactory/tmp/media/ten/ten-1.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[mov @ 0x10181cc00]sample rate not set
Output #0, mov, to '/Users/sts-107-/Dev/cloudfactory/tmp/media/ten/ten-1.mov':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 1195 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: libfaac, 0 channels, 97 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)
""
```

I couldn't figure out whats the problem.

Any suggestions are most welcome
Thank you in advance!!!